# Get value from database after clicking on image

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, jquery

I have a query that gets the latest 10 rows in a table and loops 10 times to echo HTML that includes some of the information taken from the table, to something similar like below (pseudo code):

```
query = <GET 10 LATEST ROWS FROM TABLE>

$name = <ONE VALUE FROM TABLE>;
$name2 = <ANOTHER VALUE FROM TABLE>;

echo '<div class="style1">' . $name . '</div> <a href=""><img src="image.png" /></a> <div class="style2">' . $name2 . '</div>';
```

What I'm having trouble with is that, if a user clicks the image, I need to run some Ajax to show another piece of HTML based on the variable $name.

The problem is that, since I'm echoing **10** rows from the table, how can I get the value of that one variable when the image is clicked?

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give each div an id based on the value of $name. and you use $name for your ajax call to get to next step.

Comment: So say the ten values from the database are `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10`, then make the id's `example1, example2, example3 etc...`?

Comment: yea, you can always extract the pattern and find the database values 1,2,3...by removing example if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the grouping you need.

PHP:

```
<div class="style-container">
  <div class="style1"><?=$name;?></div>
  <a href="#"><img src="image.png"></a>
  <div class="style2"><?$=name2;?></div>
</div>
```

Then you can use JS to loop through by container and get the name, no matter what the values inside may be, with or without quotes and other special characters.

JS:

```
$('.style-container').each( function( i, el ) {

  var $el  = $(el),
      name = $el.find( '.style1' ).text();

  $el.find( 'img' ).on( 'click', function() {

    $.ajax({
      url : 'whatever.php',
      data : { name : name }
    });

  });

});
```

**Note** I would only do this if using the markup is your only option. You may want to echo out a `json_encode` of data inside a JS tag. Then you can iterate and use a templating engine like `mustache` to print out the markup. Then you could use AJAX to open a URL based on the data rather than the markup.